# Projection of topological space $X\times Y$ is an open map

Tags: general-topology, product-space, open-map

I must prove that the projections $\pi_1:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_2:X\times Y\to Y$ are open, that is, they take open sets to open images. Since a basis element of $X\times Y$ is of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$. However, the collection of basis doesn't form a topology, since the intersection of two rectangles won't be a rectangle. Therefore, in order to assume an element of the set $X\times Y$, I need to take an union of basis elements, that is, $W = \cup_{i\in I} U_i\times V_i$.Therefore, I'm talking about the projection from an union to a set.

I know I could see an element of the product topology as an union of finite intersections, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247542/projection-is-an-open-map), but this is too complicated and my professor explicitly told us to search if the projection of a union of the form $W$ is the union of the projections, then that would be easy. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $W$ is open in $X\times Y$ then it can be written as a union of rectangles: $W=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)$ where $U_i$ is open in $X$ for every $i\in I$ and $V_i$ is open in $Y$ for every $i\in I$.

Consequently: $$\pi_1(W)=\pi_1\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\pi_1(U_i\times V_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$$
and:$$\pi_2(W)=\pi_2\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\pi_2(U_i\times V_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$$

Both sets are unions of open sets hence are open.