# Examples of open set as the pre-image of not open set under projection map

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the space $[0,1]^A$(the product space indexed by $A$ rather than the space of all functions from $A$ to $[0,1]$). Let $B \subset A$ be a finite set, can we have an open set of the form $\pi_B^{-1}(V)$ where $V \subset [0,1]^B$ is not necessarily open? Here $\pi_B: [0,1]^A \to [0,1]^B$ is the projection map.

Comment: I don't think so, because $\pi_B$ [is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247542/473276), and $\pi_B(\pi_B^{-1}(V)) = V$. I'm not fully sure I've understood your question - I don't understand why you're talking about the product $\sigma$-algebra when the question seems to be only about topology.